# Add 0 around all items in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, where-clause

I have a numpy array and I need to insert 0 between elements without using a `for` loop (for efficiency).

For example, `[1, 1, 2, 2]` has to return `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0]`. I thought about the `numpy.where` function, but I have no condition to use in it.

Comment: Consider removing your question from the unanswered queue by selecting an answer please.

Answer (score 3):

Either way, you'll have to make a new array. One way is to fill in a buffer of the required size:

```
result = np.zeros(2 * a.size + 1, dtype=a.dtype)
result[1::2] = a
```

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarks:

```
|---------------|-------|
|   Variant     | time  |
|---------------|-------|
|Mad Physicist  |3.54 µs|
|Python Numpy v2|4.12 µs|
|Numba v1       |2.44 µs|
|Numba v2       |2.88 µs|
|Numba v3       |2.61 µs|
|Cython         |7.26 µs|
|---------------|-------|
```

The fastest variant is Numba v1:

```
@numba.njit
def f_nb(a):
    result = np.zeros(2 * a.size + 1, dtype=a.dtype)
    result[1::2] = a
    return result
```

Other variants:

```
Mad Physicist:

    def f(a):
        result = np.zeros(2 * a.size + 1, dtype=a.dtype)
        result[1::2] = a
        return result

Python Numpy v2:

    def f2(a):
        result = np.empty(2 * a.size + 1, dtype=a.dtype)
        result[0::2] = 0
        result[1::2] = a
        return result

Numba v2:

    @numba.njit
    def f2_nb(a):
        result = np.empty(2 * a.size + 1, dtype=a.dtype)
        result[0::2] = 0
        result[1::2] = a
        return result

Numba v2:

    @numba.njit
    def f3_nb(a):
        result = np.empty(2 * a.size + 1, dtype=a.dtype)
        j = 0
        for i in range(len(result)):
            if i % 2:
                result[i] = 0
            else:
                result[i] = a[j]
                j += 1
        return result

Cython:

    %%cython -a

    import cython
    import numpy as np
    cimport numpy as np
    from numpy cimport ndarray
    from libc.stdint cimport int64_t



    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.infer_types(True)
    @cython.initializedcheck(False)
    @cython.cdivision(True)
    def f_cy64(int64_t[:] a):
        cdef int64_t i = 0
        cdef int64_t[:] result=np.empty(2 * a.size + 1, dtype=np.int64)
        cdef int64_t j = 0

        for i in range(len(result)):
            if i % 2:
                result[i] = 0
            else:
                result[i] = a[j]
                j += 1
        return np.asarray(result)
```

Initialization:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2]*1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. Numba FTW as always